# How to make asserts on the content from an Excel file?

Tags: php, excel, symfony, phpunit, assert

I have a action that returns an Excel file. Accessing that route in a browser will automatically download my Excel file.

I wrote a test for that action, but all that I can assert is the data from headers. Also, the test outputs the response directly to the console with text like `w֑m�J�9���9�e�줽o��`.

Is there a way to make asserts on data that comes from that Excel file output? The file is not saved, only the content is displayed in response.
I'm using Symfony2.

**EDIT**

I found a way to read that data by saving the response in output buffer, saving the content in a .xlsx file, converting into a .csv file and get contents from there.

```
    ob_start();
    $this->client->request(
        'GET',
        '/myUrl',
        array(),
        array(),
        array()
    );

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    file_put_contents('MyFile.xlsx', $content);
    $reader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

    $excel = $reader->load('MyFile.xlsx');

    $writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
    $writer->save('MyFileCsv.csv');

    $newContent = fgetcsv(fopen("MyFileCsv.csv", "r"));
```

Here is just a sketch. I stopped here, didn't try to read all content and make asserts, but I'm sure it can be done this way.
Ah, don't forget to delete the files after.

Comment: What do you mean by `assert`? do you try to test something or what ?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to test using phpunit. So I want to do something like 
$this->assertContains('searchWord', $response);
P.S.: I'm using Symfony2, apparently my title was changed :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use PHPexcel (can be found here: [phpexcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)) to parse your excel and assert on data collected by phpexcel

Comment: That is what I am using, but I didn't found anything about making asserts on data that is in the Excel file. I can only check the 'Content-Type' and the 'Content-Disposition', not the actual data from Excel file.

Comment: Well I used to get/modify data in excel files, but not asserting, I can't remember how, but you surely can put the data in a php string and assert on it.

Comment: Well I used to get/modify data in excel files, but not asserting, I can't remember how, but you surely can put the data in a php string and assert on it.
`$cellValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')
    ->getValue();`
Do you know the cell you have to assert on? If you do just use above call. If you don't, just make a for or a while, you are the only person who knows what's in your excel file, what structure it has. Or tell us how it looks, and what data you need to assert.

Comment: The problem is that the file is automatically downloaded. And in the console, as a response I have only characters like _w֑m�J�9���9�e�줽o��_

The $response->getContent() is null.

Comment: getContent may be a serialized data or something, I'll check the documentation.

Comment: Try example/exampleReader01.php `$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';
echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);


echo '<hr />';

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
var_dump($sheetData);` You could iterate over the array with a boolean as an answer, well it's easy to find a way for that need

Comment: Found solution. Edited question.